# Unable to MockUp a generic interface in JMockit

Tags: java, unit-testing, generics, junit, jmockit

I want to mock a generic interface:

```
public interface IModel<T, S> {
    public S classify(T entity);
}
```

This interface is sub-classed by 3 concrete classes: `TextModel`, `ImageModel`, `ScoringModel`. Each of these concrete classes have different T and S parameters.

I wrote a generic method that receives the concrete model class as an argument and generates a mocked version of the model:

```
private <T extends IModel<?, ?>> T mockModel(Class<T> modelClass) {
    return new MockUp<T>() {
        @Mock public Object classify(Object entity) { return null; }
    }.getMockInstance();
}
```

I know that `IModel::classify` has generic types for both its input and output, but I haven't found a way to use the actual generic method within the mockup.

When calling this method I get an `IllegalArgumentException`:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value of type com.classificationmanager.model.$Impl_IModel incompatible with return type com.classificationmanager.model.TextModel of com.classificationmanager.model.TextModelFactory#createModel(com.classificationmanager.model.ModelDescriptor)
>       at com.classificationmanager.model.ModelFetcherTest$5.(ModelFetcherTest.java:110)
>       at com.classificationmanager.model.ModelFetcherTest.mockAllFactories(ModelFetcherTest.java:109) ....... (spared you the rest)

I thought that getting and returning an `Object` instead of T and S was the problem, but I get the same exception when removing the mocked method and just mocking the class:

```
private <T extends IModel<?, ?>> T mockModel(Class<T> modelClass) {
    return new MockUp<T>() {
    }.getMockInstance();
}
```

I could do a switch-case and return a concrete class but that would just be nasty.

Any workaround involving the Expectations API would also work for me.

10x

Comment: Why not use `@Mocked TextModel`?

Comment: I could, but then I'll have to mock ImageModel, ScoringModel and all future concrete sub-classes of IModel

Comment: Aren't you already doing that by calling `mockModel(TextModel.class)`, as implied in the question?

Comment: @Rogério Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I need a generic method that returns a concrete sub-class of IModel according to the input parameter Class<? extends IModel>. Declaring a specific Mocked TextModel, Mocked ImageModel, etc... would not accomplish that, as it would require special treatment (declaration) for every present and future sub-class of IModel.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following examples can help (although I still don't understand the question - probable case of the XY problem).

```
public final class ExampleTest {
    public interface IModel<T, S> { S classify(T entity); }

    static class TextModel implements IModel<Integer, String> {
        @Override public String classify(Integer entity) { return "test"; }
    }

    static class ImageModel implements IModel<String, Image>  {
        @Override public Image  classify(String entity)  { return null; }
    }

    @Test
    public void createNonMockedInstanceForAnyModelClass() {
        IModel<Integer, String> m1 = mockModel(TextModel.class);
        String s = m1.classify(123);

        IModel<String, Image> m2 = mockModel(ImageModel.class);
        Image img = m2.classify("test");

        assertEquals("test", s);
        assertNull(img);
    }

    <T extends IModel<?, ?>> T mockModel(Class<T> modelClass) {
        // Or use newUninitializedInstance in case the model class doesn't
        // have a no-args constructor.
        return Deencapsulation.newInstance(modelClass);
    }

    @Test
    public void mockAllModelImplementationClassesAndInstances(
        @Capturing IModel<?, ?> anyModel
    ) {
        IModel<Integer, String> m = new TextModel();
        String s = m.classify(123);

        assertNull(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: 10x for the answer, the `Deencapsulation::newInstance` method is a nice workaround to my problem. In the 2nd test, what exactly does the field annotated by `Capturing` do? I don't see any usage of the `anyModel` input parameter within the test.

Comment: `@Capturing` extends the effect of `@Mocked` to all classes implementing/extending the declared type of the mock field/parameter (and their instances).

Comment: Yes, I know that, but in the test you provided it doesn't seem like the `TextModel` instance is mocked at all, it just calls the concrete implementation and verifies that it actually returns null. What am I missing?

Comment: If `TextModel` didn't get mocked, then `m.classify(123)` would return `"test"`, not `null`.